# Children's novel — Girl living with grandmother travels to fantasy realm through a tree

Tags: story-identification, magic, childrens-novel

It was a magical fantasy type of novel, where a girl living with I believe it was her grandmother goes through to a magical realm from a tree in their garden (I believe this tree was on the cover and had something to do with the title).

I remember a part where a rainbow was also a portal to the fantasy realm. And there was a girl who tried to catch a fish with nets made of her hair to catch a wish fish to wish for the protagonist's father or grandfather to visit her again. The protagonist accidentally caught the magic fish and got to make a wish.

It was so beautifully written but I read it more than 9 years ago at the very least.

Comment: Was it an older book when you read it? I'm wondering about one of Joan Aiken's short story collections perhaps?

Comment: Possibly one of Enid Blyton's *Faraway Tree* books. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faraway_Tree

Answer (score 1):

The Fairy Realm series by Emily Rodda!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide a bit more info on the book, and specifying the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.

Comment: Hi and welcome! LD is right! Have a look at [answer] and [help]. Oh and please take the [tour] while you're here.